# How would I go about decoding this?

Tags: python, cryptography, ascii

I have created some code that can encrypt text by converting the plaintext and key to ascii codes and multiplying them together. I know it isn't secure but I'm doing it for a cryptography class.

Here is my code

```
plaintext = input(">> ")
key = input("key: ")

def ascii(text):
    x = 0

    for i in range(len(text)):
        x += ord(text[i])*2**(8 * (len(text) -i -1 ))

    #end

    return x

#end 

ascii_pt = ascii(plaintext)
ascii_key = ascii(key)

# debug
#print(ascii_pt)
#print(ascii_key)

encoded = ascii_pt * ascii_key 

print(encoded)
```

I have tried doing `encoded / ascii_key` to no avail. Any help would be great!

**edit**

```
decoded = int(encoded / ascii_key)

print(chr(decoded))
```

this worked for small characters, but was unable to decode large ones :L

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Also, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide sample input, expected output, Stacktraces if you get errors.

Comment: Also, i think you don't use `chr()` correctly, read up [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr). It's intended for use on single charactercodes, this in the range [0, 256]

Answer (score 0):

The original length of the encoded text has to be known in order to decode it. There may be some way to infer that from the encoded value, but I couldn't think of one that would always work.

Note that this code only works for 8-bit characters (like ASCII or ISO-Latin). Given that constraint, it seemed to work correctly in both Python 2.7.13 and 3.6.1 for me.

```
from __future__ import print_function

#plaintext = input(">> ")
#key = input("key: ")

# hardcode for testing
plaintext = 'All Your Base Are Belong To Us'
key = 'secret'

def encode(text):
    x = 0
    length = len(text)
    for i in range(length):
        x += ord(text[i]) * (2 ** (8 * (length-i-1)))

    return x

def decode(value, length):
    x = value
    chars = []
    for i in range(length-1, -1, -1):
        shift = 2 ** (8 * (length-i-1))
        mask = 0xff * shift
        ch = (x & mask) // shift
        chars.append(chr(ch))
        x -= ch * shift

    return ''.join(reversed(chars))

encode_key = encode(key)
encode_pt = encode(plaintext)

print('encode_key:', encode_key)
print('encode_pt:', encode_pt)

encoded = encode_pt * encode_key

print('encoded:', encoded)
print('encoded:', hex(encoded))

decoded = decode(int(encoded // encode_key), len(plaintext))

print('decoded:', decoded)
```

Output:

```
encode_key: 126879297332596
encode_pt: 451536573816692702021325803632147813811389735036878033208035641604986227
encoded: 57290643205829835202633022894291838201313854456908334242503703290644426431694418155292
encoded: 0x1d7d9dc35af66f834a837b1a90a43725666b520a0d802d785d43d3b5213352eaa293171cL
decoded: All Your Base Are Belong To Us
```